# Can I use BTL audio amplifier IC in single-ended output configuration?

Tags: amplifier, audio, class-d, class-b-amplifier

I am designing a widget that has to have a speaker output (low power, between 1W and 2W, 8 Ohms, low-quality) with the limitation that one end of the speaker must be grounded.

There are lots of audio amplifier ICs to choose from, but all I could find have BTL outputs (they drive both ends of the speaker). **Can I use such an amplifier** (for example Class-AB [TPA6211A1](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa6211a1.pdf) or Class-D [PAM8012](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM8012.pdf)) **in a single-ended output configuration?** Will I only loose maximum power output?

I have regulated 3.3V and unregulated 7.2V (2x li-ion) available. The signal source is a 3.3V MCU. Its DAC can generate single-ended and differential signals. The MCU also has I2S interfaces.

Comment: LM386 only drives one end of the speaker. You need a big cap to block the DC.

Comment: If you want 2W single-ended, you'll need an 8W BTL output amplifier, half the volts, one quarter the power

Comment: What are your available power supply rails? We know you want less than \$2\:\text{W}\$, but how much less can you accept? What range of speaker impedances must you be able to handle? And what's driving the amplifier, exactly?